# C - Reading and 2d int array with rows terminated by 0 until end of input

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to write a program in C that will read max of 50 rows of 5 integers and print them after reaching end of stdin.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int readInput(int numbers[][5], int row) {
    int x, i = 0;
    while (1) {
        if (scanf("%d", &x) !=1 ) exit (1);
        if (x == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (feof(stdin)) {
            return 0;
        }
        numbers[row][i] = x;
        i++;
    }
}

int main ( void ) {
    int numbers[50][5];
    int row = 0; int val;
    int i,j;
    while (1) {

        val = readInput(numbers, row);
        if ( val == 1){
            row++;
            continue;
        } else if (val == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < row+1; i++) {
        for ( j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            printf("%d ", numbers[i][j]);
        }printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Problem is that no matter how I try to tell the program that the endless loop in main needs to end, it never does. I really need to understand the concept of reaching end of input, that is why I dont want to simply write a loopthat finishes after a certain amount of iterations, I want to learn how to break the loop after reaching end of stdin.

Comment: Did you try inputting the EOF character? CTRL + D (Or CTRL + Z on windows)

Comment: What do you think is `eof` of `stdin`? On linux you should use `CTRL+D` to trigger it.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16333/how-to-signal-the-end-of-stdin-input

Comment: BTW `!=1 ) exit (1);` is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code doesn't capture the EOF that `scanf` may return.

You can try something like:

```
int readInput(int numbers[][5], int row) {
    int x, i = 0;
    while (1) {
      int t = scanf("%d", &x);  // Save return value
      if (t == EOF) return 0;   // Check for EOF
      if (t !=1 ) exit (1);

      if (x == 0) {
          return 1;
      }

      numbers[row][i] = x;
      i++;
    }
}
```

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> for windows) can be used to indicate EOF

Comment: Yes, I know I can send and EOF signal with ctrl+d, my question was how can I break the loop in the main. Saving return value of scanf did this: whenever I try ctrl+d, the exit(1) is called and program ends. If I remove the line with exit(1), then the loop in the main never ends and always asks for one more row, as if t==EOF never happened.